# Extract information from HTML when it is retrieved using JSON

Tags: html, json, vb.net, google-chrome

I got this part of code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrapper clearfix" id="content">
        <section class="clearfix">
<article id="market_data" ng-app="eex.market_data" data-src="/blueprint/" data-config="/json/en/20776/content.json?config=" class="ng-cloak">
      <div id="content">
        <div market-data-page-title></div>
        <div market-data-datepicker></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </article>
</section>
</div>
```

Where some data is retrieved using json, which makes the final HTML invisible to me, talking about code. I need to get some data that is drawed on the HTML using VB.NET, so I download the whole file and search for what I need but it isn't there.

Is there a way to catch this information?? I thought maybe using some Chrome extension where I can see all the transfers through TCP, I remember using one but can't recall the name now!!

Thanks a lot

Ricardo

Comment: It looks like they are using AngularJS. This is the URL: http://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/derivatives-market/french-financial-futures#!/2014/05/06

Comment: Finally managed to find the JSON and download it into a string, then deserialize it using JavaScriptSerializer. To find the URL where the Website was getting the JSON from, I used the Chrome Extension called Live HTTP Headers.